# How do I escape reserved words used as column names? Google Data Studio

Tags: escaping, looker-studio

I am using Google data studio to produce some data dashboards, as part of this I am creating a calculated field on the dataset that strips the numeric value from an alphanumeric string i.e. 7 out of 7A.

I'm then using a case statement to assign another number to the striped value i.e where the formula returns 7 the case statement assigns this to 1000, 8 as 2000, 9 to 3000 ect

The problem I am having is that in the dataset three of the fields are titled 7, 8 and 9. As such in the below formula the first three lines are comparing the striped field to the fields titled 7, 8 or 9 and not to the numeric value of 7, 8 or 9

I need to be able to escape the 7,8 or 9 characters in the formula so they are treated as a numeric value and not a referance to a field in the dataset.

```
case
    when CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(YearGroup, R"\D+", "") AS NUMBER)= 7 then 1000
    when CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(YearGroup, R"\D+", "") AS NUMBER)= 8 then 2000
    when CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(YearGroup, R"\D+", "") AS NUMBER)= 9 then 3000
    when CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(YearGroup, R"\D+", "") AS NUMBER)= 10 then 4000
    when CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(YearGroup, R"\D+", "") AS NUMBER)= 11 then 5000
    when CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(YearGroup, R"\D+", "") AS NUMBER)= 12 then 6000
    when CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(YearGroup, R"\D+", "") AS NUMBER)= 13 then 7000
end
```

Comment: **Needs details [REVISION 1]**: Provide a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report [TO-DO] and sample data set(s) / shared Google Sheet [TO-DO] of the scenario, that shows 1) Input table(s) (~9 rows) / chart in both Question [TO-DO] and Report [TO-DO] 2) Expected table / charts in both Question [TO-DO] & Report [TO-DO] 3) Issue / attempt at solving in both Question [DONE: Needs context 1&2] & Report [TO-DO]. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to visualise and pinpoint a suggestion to a specific use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To strip a part of a string, please use `REGEXP_EXTRACT`.

First check for a number, the text may only contain digits. If it is a number convert the text field to a number.

If the text field contains digits (`\d+`) followed by a none digit (`\D`), the extract the digits. Convert it to a number and do your calculation.

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(YearGroup, r"\d+") THEN CAST(YearGroup AS number )
  WHEN CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(YearGroup, r"(\d+)\D") AS number ) BETWEEN 7 AND 13 THEN 
    1000 * ( CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(YearGroup, r"(\d+)\w") AS number ) - 6 )
  ELSE NULL
END
```